# Navigationbar disappear in detailview Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview, uinavigationbar

I am making an iPhone app for browsing alcohol spirits in a tableView. I have a searchBar hooked up to the tableView so its searchable. You can click each cell to get to a detailView with more information about the product. Both the MasterTableViewController and the detailViewController are embedded in a navigation controller, so you can get back from the detailView.

Now to the problem:
When clicking on a cell there is 25% chance of loading a Admob interstitial ad. 
- If you don't search and click, the ad comes, you quit it and you arrive to the detailView with the navigation bar as it's supposed.

- IF you search and THEN click, the ad comes, you quit it and then the navigation bar is GONE. You are stuck to the detailView.

Any ideas, how comes?

Can I reload the navigationbar in some way?

Comment: I had a same issue in my project.i was able to managed.you need to do two thing on your detailVC inside your segue UISearchbar.searchbar.isActive = false and on both VC set your navigation bar inside your viewDidAppers to this navigationBarController.navigationbar.isHidden = false . Hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: please show some code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try this in detail view?

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: animated)
}
```